# Asp.net MVC Calling Controller In Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller. This controller take some values. I am listing my values in view with html a tag.

when a tag clicked javascript function running

```
function redirectList(countyID,cuisineID)
{               
    var time = new Date();
    var localtime = time.toLocaleTimeString();

    $.ajax({
        method: "Post",
        url: "@Url.Action("Index","Restaurants")",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({ LocalTime: localtime, CountyID: countyID, CuisineID: cuisineID }),
        success: function (data) { alert('Oldu'); },
        failure: function (errMsg) { alert('Olmadı'); }
    });     
}

<a  onclick="redirectList(@Model.CountyID,@item.CusineID)" class="CountyCuisine">@item.Name</a>
```

For data coming to the Controller, there is no problem.

The Controller returns data to the redirected View fine. But the page is not redirected. I don't want run this Async. I want it so that when I sent data to the Controller, it must redirect to another page.

I cannot find the problem and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are performing an ajax. Your success method doesn't redirect you..so do you want to redirect here and to where?

Comment: I want redirect to my controller action . 
Exp: Function Index(Optional ByVal deliverytypes As DeliveryType = Nothing, Optional ByVal CuisineID As Integer = 0, Optional ByVal CountyID As Integer = 0, Optional ByVal LocalTime As DateTime = Nothing) As ActionResult

Comment: So you want to perform an ajax to the server. The server will do some logic and then redirect you?
Will he always redirect you? or is this based on some logic?

Comment: Action recieve my sent data and doing some process and prepare returning data for showing view. This view not same its another view .

Comment: You can't do a RedirectToAction in an Ajax call. You have to return some JSON with the URL and do it in you JS. This has been asked and answered countless times before.

Comment: Ok, so you return data to this view as a response from you ajax call.
Now after returning the data when and how do you want to redirect?

Comment: yes i want sent data to controller and show this controller view.